# Is this indicative of a memory leak in Java?

Tags: java, memory

Does the following graph indicate that I am using memory and it is not being garbage collected?

[image]

I expected the orange graph (the allocated heap) to go down once I start using less of the heap.

- Is this an invalid assumption?
- Once allocated, does the heap not
  shrink until the program closes?

Comment: On most JVMs, once heap is allocated it does not shrink until the program ends.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is clear from the graph that your JVM is capable of shrinking the heap. This can be seen from the orange line taking a slight dip just before 3:10pm.

However, later on the JVM chooses to not shrink the heap. This is almost certainly because an insufficiently large fraction of the heap is unused. The behaviour is controlled by `-XX:MinHeapFreeRatio` and `-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio`.

For a discussion, see http://stopcoding.wordpress.com/2010/04/12/more-on-the-incredible-shrinking-jvm-heap/

Comment: +1 look at how much is used after each full GC. You can trigger additional ones if you need to but a lack of full GCs indicates you don't have a problem (or your leak is very slow)